# how to change location of localhost?

Tags: apache2, localhost

I installed apache2, mysql, php and phpmyadmin . The root location is in `/var/www` now but i wanted to change it to something like `/home/user/sites` or something. In the other threads , the solution was adding some code in the `000-default.conf` file in `sites-enabled` folder , but there is no such file in my folder, infact there is no file in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled` folder. So how do i change the location now?

```
$ ls -l  /etc/apache2/sites-enabled
total 0

$ ls -l /etc/apache2/sites-available
total 16
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1582 अक्टूबर 17 07:26 000-default.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1338 अक्टूबर 13 22:51 000-default.conf~
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 6432 जुलाई  21  2013 default-ssl.conf

$ apt-cache policy apache2
Installed: 2.4.6-2ubuntu2.2
  Candidate: 2.4.6-2ubuntu2.2
  Version table:
 *** 2.4.6-2ubuntu2.2 0
        500 http://np.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-updates/main i386 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-security/main i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.4.6-2ubuntu2 0
        500 http://np.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy/main i386 Packages
```

Content of `000-default.conf` is:

```
$ cat /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf     
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    #ServerName www.example.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /home/buffhead/Sites
    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
DocumentRoot /home/buffhead/Sites/
<Directory />
Options FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride None
</Directory>
<Directory /home/buffhead/Sites/>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
AllowOverride None
Order allow,deny
allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

And content of new DocumentRoot:

```
$ ls -l /home/buffhead/Sites/
total 4
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 25 अक्टूबर 13 15:12 info.php
```

Comment: Please edit your post and add the output of `ls -l  /etc/apache2/sites-enabled`, `ls -l /etc/apache2/sites-available` and `apt-cache policy apache2`.

Answer (score 1):

To change the default location, edit `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf`. Then do:

```
sudo a2ensite 000-default.conf
sudo service apache2 restart
```

And upgrade to Ubuntu 14.04 while you're at it. 13.10 is obsolete and no longer supported.

The permission error might be because it doesn't have access to the `/home/buffhead/Sites/` folder. Do:

```
chmod o+x /home/buffhead
chown :www-data -R /home/buffhead/Sites/
chmod g+rxs /home/buffhead/Sites/
```

This should let apache access the files in `/home/buffhead/Sites/`, and files created in it should retain the `www-data` group.

Comment: what to edit? i tried adding   DocumentRoot /home/buffhead/Sites/
<Directory />
Options FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride None
</Directory>
<Directory /home/buffhead/Sites/>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
AllowOverride None
Order allow,deny
allow from all
</Directory>  still not working

Comment: @prasannamishra that could be due to any number of reasons: permissions issues, configuration errors, etc. Hard to tell. Edit your question, and post the output of `cat /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf`, and the output of `ls -l /home/buffhead/Sites/`.

Comment: After editing 000-default in sites-available , the error 404 changed to error 403 Forbidden You don't have permission to access /info.php on this server.